# ssh port number set too large: cannot login

Tags: ssh, port

i just set my ssh port over the maximum number 65535 like 78910

and it refused me to login, i've also tried

`78910, 8910 and 7891`

and not working...default port 22 is not working too.

any good idea?

```
    it's a simple question but the editor keep warning me not meet the 
    qualify...so i have to put some more words in it, sorry.
```

Comment: solved, using vps

Answer (score 0):

Verify you have added new port into firewall service (iptables). Also update selinux permissions if it is enable on your server.